# Dockerized NodeJS choose a script on npm run

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack

I need to dockerize a nodejs application that uses webpack. I have this script below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open webpack --env.envConfig=hello --config configs/webpack.dev.js ",
    "build-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --env.project=rm --env.envConfig=hello --env.publicPath=/ --config configs/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.project=rm --env.envConfig=hello --env.publicPath=/ --config configs/webpack.prod.js",
  },
```

This is my docker code snippet

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY . /build

WORKDIR /build

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && npm run build
```

However, I want to choose between `npm run build` and `npm run build-dev` whenever I execute `docker run`. Is it possible? If not, can I pass the webpack options on `docker run` instead?

Comment: no, you cannot choose between them. the image is built with those commands. but
what you can do is create later which runs a command, and another later for another command. sometimes it is used as a build layer and a code execution. sometimes a layer to run tests and so on.

Comment: You can run any command after the docker image is built... but the files will only exist while that container exists. `docker run npm build` `docker run npm build-dev`.  Maybe you want to choose which image to build? rather than what command to run after the image is built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container image can be selectively built with a [build argument](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) using `--build-arg`

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY . /build

WORKDIR /build

ARG BUILD_TYPE build

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN set -uex; \
    npm install; \
    npm run $BUILD_TYPE
```

```
$ docker build --build-arg BUILD_TYPE=build-dev --tag me/app:build-dev .
$ docker build --tag me/app .
```

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot choose between them. the image is built with those commands. but what you can do is create layer which runs a different command.

sometimes it is used as a build layer, sometimes a layer to run tests and so on.

a sample of a multilayer build is this one:

https://github.com/BretFisher/docker-mastery-for-nodejs/blob/master/multi-stage-test/Dockerfile

you can use docker-compose to run a specific layer:

```
version: "3.7"


services:

  my-service:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      target: dev
    image: my-service
```

you can change the target to be the layer that you want to run